# Trying to declare a member-object in C++

Tags: c++, list, object, initialization, member

I'm trying to declare a member-object in a class in C++, like so:

```
class bankAccount
{
public:
  bankAccount(int, int, int, string, int);
private:
  bankBranch homeBranch;
};

bankAccount::bankAccount(int accountNumber, int accountBalance, int homebsbnumber, 
string homeaddress, int homepostcode) : homeBranch(homebsbnumber, homeaddress, homepostcode) {}
class bankBranch
{
public:
/** bankBranch(const int& bsbNumber, const string& address, const int& postCode) 
{ 
    this->bsbNumber = bsbNumber;
    this->address = address;
    this->postCode = postCode;
}; **/

bankBranch(int, string, int);
void setPostCode() 
{ 
    cout << "Please type in the postal code of your bankBranch: " << endl;
    cin >> postCode;
}
void setBsbNumber()
{ 
    cout << "Please type in the BSB Number of your bankBranch: " << endl;
    cin >> bsbNumber;

}
void setAddress() 
{ 
    cout << "Please type in the address of your bankBranch " << endl;
    cin >> address;
}
// Return methods for bsb number, address and post code
int getBsbNumber() 
{
    return this->bsbNumber;
}
string getAddress() 
{
    return this->address;
}
int getPostCode()
{ 
    return this->postCode;
}
private:
  int bsbNumber;
  string address;
  int postCode;
};
bankBranch::bankBranch(int bsbnum, string bankaddress, int bankpostcode) { 

bsbNumber = bsbnum;
address = bankaddress;
postCode = bankpostcode;

}
```

I am getting these erros:

- sytax error : missing ';' before identifier 'homeBranch'
- missing type specifier - int assumed (confused because it is obviously an object?)
- 'bankAccount' : illegal member initialization: 'homebranch' is not a base or member

I have tried many things and cannot seem to fix these errors, could anyone provide me with some insight on how to properly add the member-object bankBranch homeBranch to the class bankAccount? And how to properly use initialization lists.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the header file which defines `bankBranch` in this file(*rather translation unit*).

Since you are using composition and creating a member of `bankBranch` the compiler needs to know the details of the layout and the memory required by `bankBranch` instance, this information can only be obtained by knowing the definition of `bankBranch`. Note that forward declaration won't suffice here.

Comment: Thank-you for your help, how would I go about defining bankBranch? I'm quite a new programmer and have yet to come across something like this.

Comment: @Emmett, We have no idea what kind of class it's supposed to be, but it needs that constructor.

Comment: I'm really confused here, can someone explain this again? It's just a standard class, i.e class bankBranch { }

Comment: bankBranch is defined in my code, I just did not upload all of my code here, it is not in a separate file, I only showed you a snippet of my code.

Comment: @Emmett: If you did not show the code, How are we supposed to know? We can see only what you show.

Comment: I have updated my code, and I am still quite confused with the answer supplied, would someone care to elaborate?

Comment: define `bankBranch` before `bankAccount`